# What is the best way to structure a SCPI device class?

Tags: c#, data-structures

I am currently trying to create a class for a new SCPI controlled device we are buying at work. I have done this enough in the past to be comfortable implementing it. However, I do this often enough that it would be very nice to create a base SCPI class that I can base all future devices on. This would save me time in the future. It would make it easier to implement full control over devices instead of picking and choosing which functions I actually need and which I can disregard. It would also *hopefully* make the code easier to read in the future.

If you're not familiar SCPI stands for Standard Commands for Programmable Instruments. To me this really feels like something I could make more generic, but I'm struggling to realize it. The commands usually look like :ACQuire:AVERages? to query or :CURSor:MANual:CAX  to set a value.

I would love it if I could somehow represent this as `value = ACQuire.Averages` or `CURSor.MANual.CAX = ax`. Something like `value = ACQuire.Averages.GetData()` or `CURSor.MANual.CAX.SetData(ax)` would be fine as well. The thing is I am not educated enough in this section of computer science to come up with a reasonable approach to this. That lack of knowledge might mean this approach is fundamentally wrong. I simply don't know enough. Any pointers would be useful.

Comment: This question is way too broad for stackoverflow, to answer it properly would require intimate knowledge of SCPI and a fairly good knowledge of c#.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look into IVI drivers.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instrument_Driver

There might already be one supplied by the manufacturer.

Getting Started Guide
http://ivifoundation.org/downloads/IVI%20short%20guides%202015/Using%20IVI%20with%20C%20and%20VB.pdf

Comment: I am using the IVI drivers for the low level communication. I ended up writing a script to scrape the data sheet and then wrote a code auto generator for my device class that ised the parsed datasheet as an input.